# Is there a way to fetch computed values and group the sum of them in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a Core Data entity with the following properties (and some others):

price1 | price2 | quantity

A value for each entry is: **value = (price1 + price2) * quantity**.

I want to compute the sum of the different values grouped by a related name, but I'm struggling with it and I don't know if it's even possible.

I tried this:

```
let valueRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: RowMO.entityName)
valueRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
let priceExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "add:to:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: \RowMO.price1), NSExpression(forKeyPath: \RowMO.price2)])
let valueExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "multiply:by:", arguments: [priceExpression, NSExpression(forKeyPath: \RowMO.quantity)])
let sumExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [valueExpression])
let sumDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
sumDescription.expression = sumExpression
sumDescription.name = "sum"
sumDescription.expressionResultType = .doubleAttributeType
valueRequest.propertiesToFetch = [#keyPath(RowMO.file.name), sumDescription]
valueRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = [#keyPath(RowMO.file.name)]
```

But I get this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Bad argument to aggregate total in select (must be a keypath or constant value) : (
> "(price1 + price2) * quantity" )'

I think I understand the problem but how can I manage to do that (without fetching all the entries in-memory and compute the sums)?